# Multiple search and replace in one line

Tags: vim

If I do something like:

> :%s/aaa/bbb/ | %s/111/222/

and the first search and replace doesn't find any matches, the second search and replace won't be executed. Is there any way to tell vim to carry on even when a command "failed"?

Answer (score 124, accepted):

Try

```
:%s/aaa/bbb/e | %s/111/222/e
```

and read

```
:help :s_flags
```

especially the entry under **[e]**:

```
 When the search pattern fails, do not issue an error message and, in
 particular, continue in maps as if no error occurred.  This is most
 useful to prevent the "No match" error from breaking a mapping.  Vim
 does not suppress the following error messages, however:
 Regular expressions can't be delimited by letters
 \ should be followed by /, ? or &
 No previous substitute regular expression
 Trailing characters
 Interrupted
```

Comment: Note to prefix every `s` with a `%`. When I tried this I accidentally only put a `%` in front of the first replacement. The command will still run without error but it will not do the replacements you expect it to carry out.

Comment: Do this with all buffers by prefixing with `:bufdo`. i.e. `:bufdo %s/a/b/g | ...`