# vim substitute mulitple characters in a line

Tags: vim

Command `:%s:a:b` will modify line `aaa` to line `baa`. The question is how to get result `bbb` using only one command (not using `:%s:a:b` 3 times, what I am doing now :-) ).

Comment: apart from the `g` flag, your command `:%s...` is not substitution **in a line**. it is in whole buffer. double check the substitution result, if it is really what you were expecting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add `g` flag at the end, like this:

```
:%s:a:b:g
```

When working with regular expressions this flag commonly means a "global" replacement, i.e. replace all occurrences.

The same technique usually works in other tools too that use regular expressions, for example `sed`, `perl`, etc.

**UPDATE**

I am surprised that such a simple answer still keeps receiving upvotes... So for you `vim` fans out there I recommend this great site where I still keep learning interesting new stuff: http://vimcasts.org/

Answer (score 0):

remember the 'e' flag

> :%s:a:b:e

Have a look at this answer [Multiple search and replace in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4737099/multiple-search-and-replace-in-one-line)